# Is it possible to add an Hbox in StackPane?

Tags: java, javafx, stackpanel, hbox

As you can see i'm a junior dev and new in the stackOverflow community .
So please don't tell me i'm stupid ( or i least why :) )

I'm writing a little application in javaFx and i'm facing a little issue where i've worked on all the afternoon .

So i have this program with this class :

```
package glintSG.view.mainPane;

 import java.awt.Dimension;

 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
 import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class CountDown extends HBox {

private Text countDownLabel;

public CountDown() {
    super();        
}   

public HBox buildCountDown() {
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.setId("countDownBox");
    countDownLabel = new Text();
    countDownLabel.setId("countdownlabel-SG");
    //position of the count down adapted to the screen size
    relocateCountDown();    
    countDownLabel.getStyleClass().add("countdownlabel-SG");
    hb.getChildren().add(countDownLabel);
    hb.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    return hb;      
}

public Text getCountDownLabel() {
    return countDownLabel;
}   

public void relocateCountDown() {
    countDownLabel.setTranslateX(Main.getWindowWidth()/2);      
}
}
```

And now if i'm calling it in my view  it is working :

```
package glintSG.view;

public class SGView  {

private EnterHeadingPane enterHeadingPane;
private CountDown countDown;

@Override
public void preInit() {
    countDown = new CountDown();
    enterHeadingPane = new EnterHeadingPane();
}

@Override
public void init() {
getRootNode().getChildren().add(countDown.buildCountDown());
getRootNode().getChildren().add(enterHeadingPane.buildEnterCap());
}
}
```

(As you can see i really reduced the class for you to be more readable, don't hesitate if you need more about the class)

But if i do that it works.
What i don't understand is when i don't want to put my countdown in the main image but in a sub stackpane , nothing is showing .
If i put my countdown in this class  :

```
package glintSG.view.mainPane;

public class EnterHeadingPane extends StackPane {

private Group group;

private Button tryButtonCAP;
private TextField inputTextCAP;
private Text textLabel;
private CountDown countDown;
private DifficultyLvlBox diffLvl;

private double textFieldPaddingTop = 7.0;
private double textFieldPaddingBot = 09.0;
private double textFieldPaddingLeft = 10.0;
private double textFieldPaddingRight = 10.0;

private double ButtonPaddingTop = 10.0;
private double ButtonPaddingBot = 10.0;
private double ButtonPaddingLeft = 10.0;
private double ButtonPaddingRight = 10.0;

private CustomTextField capTextField;
private boolean isWarningHere = false;

private Dimension dimension = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();


public EnterHeadingPane() {
    super();
    this.getStyleClass().add("glint-title-window");
}

public StackPane buildEnterCap() {
    final StackPane enterCap = new StackPane();
    enterCap.setId("enterCapLayer");
    textLabel = buildTextLabel();
    inputTextCAP = buildTextFieldCap();
    tryButtonCAP = buildCapButton();
    countDown =buildCountDown();
    group = new Group();
    group.getChildren().add(tryButtonCAP);
    group.getChildren().add(inputTextCAP);
    group.getChildren().add(textLabel);
    group.getChildren().add(countDown);
    group.getChildren().add(diffLvl);
    group.setTranslateX(getScreenWidth() - 
          textLabel.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() - 50);
    group.setTranslateY(900);
    enterCap.getChildren().add(group);
    return enterCap;
}
//well i write the methods buildTextLabel etc.

private CountDown buildCountDown() {
    countDown = new CountDown();
    countDown.setId("countDown-SG");
    countDown.buildCountDown();
    countDown.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return countDown;
}
}
```

And then if i do that my countdown is not printed .
Why ?

So i think the main question is : Is it possible to put a hbox in a stackpane , but i think it is . 
So i need you for helping me :)
If anyone know why , pls help me :)

Answer (score 2):

In your first example it works because you use

```
getRootNode().getChildren().add(countDown.buildCountDown());
```

And when you call `countDown.buildCountDown()` you create a new HBox and return it.

In your second example

```
private CountDown buildCountDown() {
    countDown = new CountDown();
    countDown.setId("countDown-SG");
    countDown.buildCountDown();
    countDown.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return countDown;
}
```

It does not work because you return your CountDown object which extends `HBox` but which is empty.

You actually made a mistake with your CountDown class.

Either you should use your countdown class as HBox as follows :

```
public class CountDown extends HBox {

    private Text countDownLabel;

    public CountDown() {
        super();
        // Initializes your CountDown.
        buildCountDown();
    }

    public void buildCountDown() {
        // Not needed to instantiate a new HBox, your countdown object is extending this kind of Node
        this.setId("countDownBox");
        countDownLabel = new Text();
        countDownLabel.setId("countdownlabel-SG");

        //position of the count down adapted to the screen size
        relocateCountDown();

        countDownLabel.getStyleClass().add("countdownlabel-SG");
        // Add the label to your CountDown object.
        this.getChildren().add(countDownLabel);
        this.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    }


    public Text getCountDownLabel() {
        return countDownLabel;
    }


    public void relocateCountDown() {
        countDownLabel.setTranslateX(Main.getWindowWidth()/2);      
    }
}
```

And when you instantiate your CountDown object, you can add it in your `Group` or in your `StackPane`.

Or you could use your object initializing an HBox attribute and retrieve it by a getter :

```
public class CountDown {

    private Text countDownLabel;

    private HBox container;

    public CountDown() {
        super();
        // Initializes your CountDown.
        buildCountDown();
    }

    // Your method
    public void buildCountDown() {
        container = new HBox();
        container.setId("countDownBox");
        countDownLabel = new Text();
        countDownLabel.setId("countdownlabel-SG");

        //position of the count down adapted to the screen size
        relocateCountDown();

        countDownLabel.getStyleClass().add("countdownlabel-SG");
        container.getChildren().add(countDownLabel);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    }

    // You can access to your HBox here
    public HBox getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public Text getCountDownLabel() {
        return countDownLabel;
    }

    public void relocateCountDown() {
        countDownLabel.setTranslateX(Main.getWindowWidth()/2);      
    }
}
```

The `Hbox` "container" will be initialized in the same time as your object CountDown as `buildCountDown` method is called in the CountDown constructor. And you can access it via the getter `CountDown#getContainer()`.

Comment: Hi ! thanks for the answer but i don't understand something , why do you  say my HBox was empty while i was building it in my method `buildCountDown()` ?

Comment: You are not, you are creating a new HBox, while you could use your CountDown class which is extending the HBox. Do not create a new one in your `buildCountDown`method, just use `this`.

Comment: I think you are right , now it is printing what i want , i just need to place it well and that will do the trick !  Thanks a lot !

Comment: If the previous HBox you had in your `buildCountDown()` method was well placed,  you also could use the second solution, do not extend HBox anymore and add a getter to retrieve the HBox you build in the `buildCountDown()` method.